# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 5?

Tags: gridview, datatable

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 5.

I have the folowing codeblock in my application. This is to enable me to remove rows from a gridview without deleting the same rows completley from the database!

The problem is I am able to remove values but not all of the values when i select in a particular order or more than 3!

This is the error I'm met with!

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 5.

The comented catch exeption solves the problem slightly.

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT UserId, staffNo, forename, surname FROM userProfilesTbl WHERE st_id=@st_id AND wa_id=@wa_id ORDER BY surname ASC "
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st_id", myLblSt.Value().ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wa_id", myLblWa.Value().ToString)

        Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataConn(cmd)
        'Try
        For Each dr In GridView1.Rows

            Dim chkBox As CheckBox = dr.FindControl("RowLevelCheckBox")

            If chkBox.Checked = True Then

                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(dr.RowIndex)
                dt.AcceptChanges()

            End If
        Next
        'Catch ex As Exception

        'End Try
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here:

```
 dt.Rows.RemoveAt(dr.RowIndex)
```

This deletes out of the collection so on the next iteration the row indexes in dr are no longer valid.

You want to go from higher towards lower RowIndex values to avoid this problem.

Comment: Hi 500 - Internal Server Error, as this is the first time I've done this can you give me a little more information as to how this can be achieved? script snippet!

Comment: Can you expand on "You want to go from higher towards lower RowIndex values to avoid this problem." please?

Comment: Rather than using a For Each loop, in this case use a regular For loop with an index counter going from count-1 down to zero. That way the index of the remaining items doesn't change when you remove items.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the reason that when you are removing the rows, other indexes are getting updated. For example, if you have 5 rows and you wish to remove row 1, 3 and 5 (index 0, 2, 4).

So let's assume the following is your data grid:

```
Index|Data
0--------A
1--------B
2--------C
3--------D
4--------E
```

After you remove 1<sup>st</sup> row (index 0):

```
Index|Data
0--------B
1--------C
2--------D
3--------E
```

After removing 3<sup>rd</sup> row (index 2):

```
Index|Data
0--------B
1--------C
3--------E
```

Now if you will try to remove 5<sup>th</sup> row (index 4), you'll get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` because there is no row at position 4.

Comment: how kdo I go about rectifying this?

Comment: Try putting dt.AcceptChanges() outside ForEach loop

Comment: Hi Arpit, I've already tried that and I'm met with exactly the same error.

Comment: ok. then put all dr.RowIndex in an array
and then iterate the array in reverse order
and remove rows in reverse order
i.e. In above example first remove index 4, then 2, then 0

Comment: can you give me an example?